# Spring jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout has no effect on jmsTemplate.convertAndSend()

Tags: spring-jms

We use JmsTemplate and setting the receiveTimeout has no effect. Need help please.

```
@Bean

public JmsTemplate xyz(){


    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();

    template.setReceiveTimeout(1);

    return jmsTemplate;

}
```

jmsTemplate.convertAndSend() does not timeout with a config of 1 millisec while the log mentions that the call took about 40 millisec to complete.

P.S: We only fire the message and do not consume the message. Another team/provider does it.

Answer (score 1):

`receiveTimeout` has nothing to do with sending; it is used when the template receive operations are performed.